# Create a Card widget and call it multiple times

Tags: flutter

So im trying to build a page with lots of images in it, right now im using Stack widget to show the images,

this is my code:

```
import 'image_description.dart';

class Gallery extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white10,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
          child: InkWell(
            child: Hero(
              tag: 'back',
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/wp_back_button_icon.png',
                height: 250,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 20, 0),
            child: Hero(
              tag: 'logo',
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/wp_logo.png',
                height: 250,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Text(
                'AR Gallery',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text("Let's educate in the fun way"),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: double.infinity,
                child: GridView.count(
                  primary: false,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 120,
                            width: 200,
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              child: Hero(
                                tag: 'Image1',
                                child: Image.asset(
                                    "assets/images/gallery/Image1.jpg",
                                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              child: Text('Title',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                                      color: Colors.white)),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => ImageDescription()));
                      },
                    ),
                    Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: double.infinity,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: 'Image2',
                              child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/images/gallery/Image2.jpg",
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Text('Title',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                                    color: Colors.white)),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: double.infinity,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: 'Image3',
                              child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/images/gallery/Image3.jpg",
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Text('Title',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                                    color: Colors.white)),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: double.infinity,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: 'Image4',
                              child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/images/gallery/Image4.jpg",
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Text('Title',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                                    color: Colors.white)),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: double.infinity,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: 'Image5',
                              child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/images/gallery/Image5.png",
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            child: Text('Title',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                                    color: Colors.white)),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: double.infinity,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: 'Image6',
                              child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/images/gallery/Image6.jpg",
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Text('Title',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                                    color: Colors.white)),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: double.infinity,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: 'Image7',
                              child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/images/gallery/Image7.jpg",
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Text('Title',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                                    color: Colors.white)),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: double.infinity,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: 'Image8',
                              child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/images/gallery/Image8.jpg",
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Text('Title',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                                    color: Colors.white)),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, i'm using a lot of repeated Stack widget manually.

Can I make that automated? like creating a Stack widget or something similar once, and then call it where it should be with different Title.

Regards, Slim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible, this is what we call a reusable widget.
You can create it in the same file or in a separate one. I would suggest creating a widgets folder containing a dart file (whatever you want to name it) that'll contain your reusable widget.
1- If you only want the title to be different each time it should be something like this:

```
class SpecialStack extends StatelessWidget{
  final String title;

  SpecialStack({this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
   return Stack( 
              children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          height: double.infinity,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: 'Image2',
                              child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/images/gallery/Image2.jpg",
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Text(title,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                                    color: Colors.white)),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  }
                }
```

2- If you want the image to be different whenever you use your reusable widget, it should be something like this. (I provided this case because I saw you were using different image for each Stack):

```
class SpecialStack extends StatelessWidget{
  final String title, image;

  SpecialStack({this.title, this.image});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
   return Stack( 
              children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          height: double.infinity,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: image,
                              child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/images/gallery/$image.jpg",
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Text(title,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                                    color: Colors.white)),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  }
                }
```

For the first case (only title is different),
You can just replace wherever you're using the Stack by this:

```
SpecialStack(title: "Your desired title")
```

For the second case (image and title are different):

```
SpecialStack(title: "Your desired title", image: "your_image_name")
```

I hope this helps. I tried to be as clear as possible.

Comment: Another awesome answer, thanks, but now comes the new one. How can i get the `SpecialStack(title: "Your desired title", image: "your_image_name")` to be passed to another page? 1. created the widget, 2. call the widget on 2nd screen and put special variable, 3. get the special variable on the 3rd screen (after clicking that 2nd page widget). As you can see i want to pass the Hero tag and the Title on 3rd page

Comment: Or simply, how to pass the **title** and the **image** to multiple pages?

Comment: You can call the your reusable widget wherever you want, you just have to import it at the top and you should be able to use it.
Or I don't know if it is about something else.

Comment: If the answer was somehow helpful please upvote it as well :)

Comment: Yes i understand about calling the reusable widget anywhere. But question is, how can i get the this.title to from that widget another widget?

Comment: My rep point is below the required to upvote, but i yes i did

Comment: So you want to pass the information you pass into your reusable widget to another widget in another screen?

Comment: THAT'S RIGHT, it's so hard for me to say hehe

Comment: Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is. I think you should ask another question but yea go ahead. How are you navigating to that new screen?

Comment: Yes yes, i did, i posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620054/how-to-get-data-from-previous-page-flutter/62621440#62621440)
im using MaterialPageRoute, you can see all in the link

Comment: i still don't get it clear with the answer, you can see the comments there. If yours solve mine, i can upvote and mark your as an answer instead'

Comment: Well okay but this should be discussed on the other question's page. I'll try to answer it. My point was that if you found the answer provided on this page helpful you should upvote it but yea I'll try to answer your other question on the other page.

Comment: I'll upvote both and include the answer on both page as reference

Answer (score 0):

keep your images in a list then map the list. and inside map define a Stack widget. it will automatically create the stacks of your list of images.

Answer (score 0):

You should write one function return widget type. Every time you want to show image you can call it.
Ex

```
Widget showImage(String url, String text){
return Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: double.infinity,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: 'Image8',
                              child: Image.asset(
                                  "url,
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Text(text,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                                    color: Colors.white)),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
}
```

Comment: This is what im looking for, but you missed something in `child: Image.asset(
                                  "url"`
the **url** must be unquoted, thanks Mate

Comment: Any idea on passing the **url** and **text** to multiple pages?

Comment: Very simple you just create a new class: Ex: class ShowImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;
  final String  title;
  const ShowImage({Key key, this.url, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(/// put above code to here);
  }
} and just import it when you want to use

Comment: Okay, i did create the new class and the variables, im trying to call it to another page, but it say `════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Class '_Type' has no instance getter 'title'.
Receiver: ImageDescription
Tried calling: title
The relevant error-causing widget was
    MaterialAp`

Comment: I also created a new thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620054/how-to-get-data-from-previous-page-flutter) to describe my problem @darkness